# How to delete a file from git/github commit history that includes sensitive data?

Tags: git, github

I realised that I included some login data in an earlier version of a project I am working on.

`project/project-v1/secret.txt`

I replaced project-v1 with project-v2 and stopped using the secrets file, so the main branch no longer contains project-v1 at all.

When I realised that I didn't want the secrets file visible in github, even though it can only be seen when looking at older commits, I tried to remove it from git and github using `git filter-repo` as detailed in [the GitHub docs](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository)

```
git filter-repo --invert-paths --path project/project-v1/secret.txt
git push origin
```

However I can still see the file when browsing the history in Github.

How can I fully remove this file from GitHub without scrapping my repo?

Comment: What were the output of those commands? From what you've said, at least one of them _must_ have failed and printed an error. If the `git filter-repo` succeeded, `git push origin` would not have worked. If `git push origin` succeeded, `git filter-repo` must not have successfully rewritten the history.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32840254/7976758 "*If you pushed to GitHub, **force pushing is not enough**, delete the repository or **contact support***"

Comment: @phd I guess that is the issue, as there weren't any error messages.  I have changed the login details, and learnt a lesson.  I don't think I really need to get GitHub support involved for this.

Comment: Then the file stucks and will be available at GH for some time until garbage collector removes it.

Answer (score -1):

I would try branching what you currently have without the sensitive information and then possibly trying git revert  on the branch with the sensitive data